# Excel Slicers for Measures

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I have a cube with two measure(count of patients) and (distinct count of visits) , and various dimension(date,program,region,etc), when I browse the cube data from excel, I can choose all the dimensions in the slicer, but my question is is there anyway i can choose the measures in the slicer? From what I see, when I insert a slicer I only get to pick the dimesnions
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you want a slicer to select between which of the two measures you are looking at, or a slicer for each, showing all the possible numbers for those counts so that you could, for example, see those items where the count of patients is equal to 5. Both of these options are possible using an extra disconnected table (or tables) and having a slicer connected to the disconnected tables. The latter option, however, requires the disconnected table to contain all the possible values for "count of patients" or "count of visits". I can explain more if you clarify which of the options you require.

Comment: If it is the latter option, a linkback table could be used to provide your disconnected list of possible values.

Comment: @gordon, I just want a slicer which gives me the option to select one of the two measures or both, I don't want the latter, could you please help me with the former?

Comment: @gordon, also can this be done without powerpivot?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure of a way around using PowerPivot to do this, short of complicated VBA scripts.

To do it with PowerPivot:

1. Create a new table with two columns. Column 1 contains the name of your measures and column 2 contains an index for each. e.g.

[image]

and add this to the Data Model (but don't create any relationships to any other tables).

2. Create a new measure with a SWITCH function that has the same relationship between the measures and their values in the Index column, e.g.

   ```
   [Chosen Measure]:=SWITCH(TRUE, MIN(MeasureTable[Index])=1, [DistinctPatients], MIN(MeasureTable[Index])=2,[DistinctDates])
   ```
3. Add the new measure to the values section of the pivot table and add the 
   Measure column from your new table to BOTH a slicer AND the column headings in the pivot table and remove the row and column totals.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to do this in tabular ssas, I have a very similar table like yours instead of index column i have 'measureid' column and i use the  following expression MeasureSelector:=switch (TRUE,
Min ( 'Measure'[MeasureID] ) = 1,
DistinctCount ([NewReferrals]),
Min ('Measure'[MeasureID]) = 2,
DISTINCTCOUNT([UniqueClients])
) but i get an error saying uniqueclients is invalid

Comment: semanticerror:column unique clients cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. This is the exact error message I get, please help!!

Comment: Does it work if you include the table name? DISTINCTCOUNT('TableName'[UniqueClients])?

Comment: gordon, this works i needed to tweak this a little bit, thanks for your help

Comment: MeasureSelector:=switch (TRUE,
Min ( 'Measure'[MeasureID] ) = 1,
DISTINCTCOUNT([SourceReferralID]),
Min ('Measure'[MeasureID]) = 2,
DISTINCTCOUNT([SourceSystemClientID])
)